# Attempts to manually change \linewidth ignored by LaTeX

Tags: margins, geometry, grouping, afterpage, everyshi

I was going to try to answer the question: [How can I change the geometry of a page on the chapter header page only, and return to normal on the next page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97079/22413)  It didn't seem like it should
be too difficult (despite the comments of some).  Well, it turned out to be
exceptionally difficult and very frustrating.

## Using the `geometry` package

Using `geometry`, it's easy to go into a document and manually change the
margins etc. and easy to restore things.  In the preamble, you simple
invoke:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

If you want to change this temporarily, you can write:

```
\savegeometry{mydefaultgeometry}
\newgeometry{margin=3in}
```

And then later you can call:

```
\loadgeometry{mydefaultgeometry}
```

I thought the solution to OP's questions might be simply solved through
some finagling of the page shipout.  I tried a number of approaches.  I
tried using `atbegshi`, `everyshi`, and `afterpage`.  All to no effect.

## It's a *local* vs. *global* issue

Then I got an idea:  maybe this was a problem of locally defined
vs. globally defined values etc.  I decided to test this out with something
simple to verify:

```
\newcommand{\myname}{AEllett}
```

Here's the MWE I tried with `afterpage`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%
\newcommand{\myname}{AEllett}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
    \chapter{#1}%
    \afterpage{\renewcommand{\myname}{someone else's name}}%
}
%% loading fancy to test whether `\renewcommand` took effect globablly
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\myname}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\mychapter{Hello}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

But if, for example, I wrote instead

```
\afterpage{\gdef\myname{someone else'sname}}
```

Then the desired effect occurred.

So I concluded that the OP's problem stemmed from the fact that

```
\afterpage{\loadgeometry{mydefaultgeometry}}
```

only sets the parameters for the page geometry locally, not globally.  (I
tried the same experiment with the package `everyshi`; same conclusion.)

## Manually reset values from within `\afterpage`

So, in order to automatically change the page geometry, I thought I could
do something like:

```
\afterpage{\setlength{\global\oddsidemargin}{1in}%
           \setlength{\global\evensidemargin}{1in}%
           \setlength{\global\textwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2in\relax}%
          }
```

But I got completely unexpected results:  namely, the changes were
inconsistently occurring.  Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=1in]{geometry}
%%
\newcommand{\myname}{AEllett}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
    \newgeometry{margin=3in}
    \chapter{#1}%
    \afterpage{\setlength{\global\oddsidemargin}{0in}%
               \setlength{\global\evensidemargin}{0in}%
               \setlength{\global\textwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2in\relax}%
               %%\setlength{\global\linewidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2in\relax}%
              }    
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\mychapter{Hello}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Something very strange is happening.

## Manually setting all page dimensions

I thought maybe there was some bad
interaction between using the `geometry` package and my manually setting
things.  So, I tried the experiment again without using the `geometry`
package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
%%
\newcommand{\myname}{AEllett}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3in}
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{3in}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{3in}
    \chapter{#1}%
    \afterpage{\setlength{\global\oddsidemargin}{0in}%
               \setlength{\global\evensidemargin}{0in}%
               \setlength{\global\textwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2in\relax}%
               %%\setlength{\global\linewidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2in\relax}%
              }    
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\mychapter{Hello}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

What I find interesting is that I am successfully able to change the
effective left-hand side margin.  But, I am not able to change the width of
the text.  Uncommenting the lines for setting `\linewidth` doesn't make
matters any better.

## Forgetting about doing anything fancy with chapters!

I decided to try to change parameters mid-document and see what happens.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]

\setlength{\global\oddsidemargin}{2in}%
\setlength{\global\evensidemargin}{2in}%
\setlength{\global\textwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4in\relax}%

\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

I get similar results.

I do not understand what is going on here.  `showframe` clearly believes
that the dimensions of the text width have been changed.  Why doesn't
LaTeX?

If I add the following to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\string\textwidth=\the\textwidth}
```

I can see that `\textwidth` has in fact been changed: and as I understand
the conversion between inches and pts, the correct values are being
displayed.

## `\linewidth` won't let me change it!!!

I tried comparing `\textwidth` to `\linewidth`.  There were discrepencies.
So I went in and manually changed `\linewidth` **to absolutely no avail!!!*

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\string\textwidth=\the\textwidth\hspace*{2em}\string\linewidth=\the\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]

\setlength{\global\oddsidemargin}{2in}%
\setlength{\global\evensidemargin}{2in}%
\setlength{\global\textwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4in\relax}%
\setlength{\global\linewidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4in\relax}%
%%\large\normalsize
%%\clearpage

\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

How is it possible to apparently have the correct `\textwidth` and yet not
have the correct `\textwidth`?  Why does LaTeX ignore what I'm doing when
I'm setting `\linewidth`?

What am I failing to understand here?

**EDIT**

I just found `\hsize`.  Setting that seems to work!  Sigh!  Effects are predictably ugly, but `\hsize` does make the necessary changes effective.

This edit might suggest that I have a solution.  I guess I do.  But, I don't really understand what I've done.  What other parameters are there that might have be reset?  Why did I have to go in and change `\hsize`, the only documentation I can find for it is in `source2e` and what I find there seems a bit obfuscatory.  :*(

So, I still welcome feedback from others who understand better what I've done.

Comment: Dear Moderators, what do I do with this question?  In the process of writing up my various attempts and ideas about how to solve my problem, I hit upon an idea that solved my dilemma.  Do I leave the question?  Is it nevertheless valuable for the community?

Comment: I didn’t read through your entire question, but you might find [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4) interesting. Also, a couple of nitpick formatting points I noticed while skimming: There’s `#`, `##`, and `###`, for headings – block quote should be saved for block quotes. I try to avoid “here” or “this” links; if you paste a SE url, it’ll be converted to the question title automagically. And I only use code markup in question titles if it would be really confusing if I didn’t, mostly because it won’t be displayed as code anyways.

Comment: A more appropriate (logical) use of `\global` is `\global\setlength{<len>}{<len>}`. You can answer things yourself on this site. We're cool like that. The community is the ultimate decider on whether something is valuable or not. But I would encourage you to write up a solution.

Comment: You are on the right track with `\hsize` as `\linewidth` is set to `\hsize` in LaTeX. `\hsize` info can be found in the TeXbook.

Comment: Manually changing `\linewidth` is something you shouldn't do; it's automatically maintained by LaTeX to reflect the current line width (particularly useful for lists).

Comment: @Werner `\global\setlength` doesn't work if the `calc` package is loaded; but `\setlength{\global<len>}{<len>}` does. :-)

Comment: all your attempts are doomed to failure, since tex (not just latex) “compiles ahead”.  so when tex comes to make a page break, it considers the block of text in which the page break is going to fall ... and it knows this because it's already compiled that block of text.  furthermore, it has no way of “uncompiling” anything, so the stuff after the split remains at the width of the page that is being committed.  which is why your changes of line width appear to have no effect.  you have to clear the page to change the line width, though things like latex `quote` environment can provide some help