# Header Margins Shrunk When Importing Style in Parent DIrectory

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I have a project directory of the nature:

- notes.sty
- class1/Index.tex
- class2/Index.tex
- classN/Index.tex

and I'm trying to usepackage the notes style for the TeX files to keep them consistent. However; whenever I import from parent directory using:

```
\usepackage{../notes}
```

Which has relevant stylings as follows:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
```

When I do this my fancy header's horizontal line acts funny:

[image: Squished header]

However, when I move the notes.sty into each directory and import them using:

```
\usepackage{notes}
```

It's correctly sized:

[image: Normal]

Does anyone have any ideas how I can keep notes.sty in the parent directory (so there's only one copy), while maintaining the correctly sized header size? I can provide more mark-up, but I didn't want to overwhelm with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

[fancyhdr not centering after changed geometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88133/fancyhdr-not-centering-after-changed-geometry)

Essentially, whenever you modify the geometry of the page you need to redefine the fancyhdr width.