# Undefined controlled sequence

Tags: control

I tried to use this template to prepare a proposal but I gut the following error message:

```
line 112:! Undefined control sequence.\resetHeadWidth ->\fancy@setoffs \resetHeadWidth
```

https://github.com/ferencek/H2020-MSCA-IF-20XY

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I’m afraid that’s not enough information for me to understand the problem. Could you please post a minimal example that reproduces this error?

Comment: Dear Davislor. I think the best way to understand the problem would be downloading the files from the link and running them. It is long and there more than one file.

Comment: In the future, I’d strongly recommend that you try to condense it to the smallest file you can that reproduces the bug.

Comment: It's quite possible that the cited link will disappear at some point, so this question would have little value for someone in the future.  It's always advisable to include all the (minimum) necessary code directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your link, it leads to a template which says in a comment that it copies [code from this answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88133/fancyhdr-not-centering-after-changed-geometry/88136#88136)  It used an undocumented internal macro from the `fancyhdr` package.

Checking back, the answer has been edited to say that `\fancy@setoffs` has a new name.  So, a command by that name is no longer defined, and you get this error. Check the link again for an updated version.

And, regulars, please be careful about posting answers that rely on undocumented features.