# Marie Curie template

Tags: compilation-error

1- Can anyone please let me know how I can reduce the top and bottom margins in the posted code? Which part do I need to edit?

2- Can anyone help me please for the following LATEX code? Main code uses include "doc1" and gets the content of doc1.tex  by

```
\include{doc1}.
```

If you want to try, please copy Main code and save as main.tex and also make a file for doc1.tex

You write something in doc1.tex and compile it and then go to main.tex and compile it shows the pdf.

I always get the following error message when I compile doc1.tex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \section{Excellence}The control sequence at the end of the top line
```

**Main Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}



\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
% HotFix from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300259/84485
% Version1 of titlesec is not compatible with the latest texlive. 
% Either the titlesec package must be updated, or the following HotFix used:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{soul} % for smarter (word-wrapping) underlining
\setul{1pt}{.4pt} % 1pt below contents
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{[\textbf{TODO:} #1]}}}
% \titlespacing\section{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8bp}{1em}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\autocite} % citations in footnotes
\bibliography{bibliography}

\headheight=14pt

% Explicitly set footnote font size to match call (i.e., 8pt).
% Taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249422/84485
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{8}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={H2020-MSCA-IF-2018},    % title
    pdfauthor={},
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
  }

\newcommand{\markStartPageLimit}{%
\begin{flushright}
\textcolor{red}{{\large {\bf START PAGE COUNT \--- MAX 10 PAGES~~~~~}}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}
}\vspace{-.5cm}
\end{flushright}
}
\newcommand{\markEndPageLimit}{%
\vfill
\begin{flushright}
\textcolor{red}{{\large {\bf STOP PAGE COUNT \--- MAX 10 PAGES~~~~~}}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}
}
\end{flushright}
}


% To correctly align fancy headers.
% Courtesy of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88136/84485
%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\resetHeadWidth}{\fancy@setoffs}
%\makeatother

\makeatletter
  \ifcsname f@nch@setoffs\endcsname\else%
  %% If \fancy@setoffs does not exis, then we assume old version define it to be
  %% fancy@setoffs, which is the old name for it:
  \let\f@nch@setoffs\fancy@setoffs
\fi
\makeatother

\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\lhead{MCSA}\rhead{SE}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetHeadWidth}{\f@nch@setoffs}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


% For CV
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


%List of acronyms used in the proposal 
%read the acronym package manual for details: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf
%\acs{PropAcronym} gives acronym [in square brackets]
%\acl{PropAcronym} gives long form of acronym, probably not used {in second set of braces}
%\acf{PropAcronym} gives both
\begin{acronym}
\acro{IF}{Individual Fellowships}
\acro{PropAcronym}[PROPOSAL ACRONYM]{This is my proposal's acronym}
\end{acronym}

\begin{document}
%mark proposal acronym as used, such that the short-hand form is always used by default.
\acused{PropAcronym}
%\begin{linenumbers}

\include{doc1}

%\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

**doc1 code:**

```
\section{Excellence} \label{sec:excellence} %\footnote{Literature should be listed in footnotes, font size 8 or 9. All literature references will count towards the page limit.}
 
\subsection{Quality and credibility of the research/innovation action (level of novelty, appropriate consideration of inter/multidisciplinary aspects)} \label{sec:excellence_quality}
  
\subsubsection{Introduction and the state-of-the-art.}
  
\subsubsection{An overview of the action and the ER's previous related works.}
 
\subsubsection{Specific objectives and research methodology}
 
\subsubsection{Originality, innovative and interdisciplinary aspects of the project} 
 
%\subsubsection{Interdisciplinary aspects of the project}
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized my edit messed up the comments in the code, so I rolled it back. Could you re-paste your code into your question, but use code markup instead of quotation markup?

Comment: `doc1.tex` can not be compiled on its own. If you change something in `doc1.tex` simply save the changes, go to `main.tex` and compile it.

Comment: Thanks, great. Actually, this solved my question. I will keep the question here, it might help other people as well.

Comment: I am new to the platform so I have also the following question: when I copy from my file a long code, how can I post it here in the code markup? where is code markup?

Comment: Paste your code, select it and  click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) or press strg + k to highlight code.

Comment: Present version of `titlesec` is `2.11`, not `1`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks good now.

Comment: Can anyone please let me know how I can reduce the top and bottom margins in the posted code? Which part do I need to edit?

Comment: @leandriis Please can you read last comment of the user? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Probabilitystudent: To change the top and bottom margins without affecting the left and right margins, you might want to use the `top=...` and `bottom=...` options of the `geometry` package. If this did not help you, please consider opening a new question on this topic as your request here won't be seen by many people.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Could you please be so kind to explain to my how the additional request of the OP is related to me?

Comment: @leandriis Sincerely I have thinked to you by two your comment. I'm sorry if I have disturbed you.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Please don't worry, you did not disturb me with your comment. I was just wondering.