# Marie Curie template citation style

Tags: biblatex, achemso

I'm trying to change the citation style for this template for the Marie-Curie Individual Fellowship (https://github.com/ferencek/H2020-MSCA-IF-20XY) from verbose-inote to chem-acs. In replacing the line:

`\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

with

`\usepackage[style=chem-acs,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

the citation in the footnote disappears. Anyone have any ideas for how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Edit: Below I have added a minimum working example. Apologies that it still does not look very `minimal'; the format required for the submission is quite elaborate. What a shame to use to have to make Latex do this!

```
\begin{filecontents}{mwe_refs.bib}
@article{schrock_molybdenum_1986,
    title = {Molybdenum},
    volume = {10},
    shorttitle = {Mo},
    doi = {10.10001},
    number = {46},
    journal = {Chem. Commun.},
    author = {Schrock R. R.},
    year = {1986},
    pages = {3--4}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
% HotFix from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300259/84485
% Version1 of titlesec is not compatible with the latest texlive. 
% Either the titlesec package must be updated, or the following HotFix used:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother

%style=verbose-inote
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{soul} % for smarter (word-wrapping) underlining
\setul{1pt}{.4pt} % 1pt below contents
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{[\textbf{TODO:} #1]}}}
% \titlespacing\section{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8bp}{1em}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\autocite} % citations in footnotes

\bibliography{mwe_refs}

\headheight=14pt

% Explicitly set footnote font size to match call (i.e., 8pt).
% Taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249422/84485
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{8}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={H2020-MSCA-IF-2020},    % title
    pdfauthor={},
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
  }

\newcommand{\markStartPageLimit}{%
\begin{flushright}
\textcolor{red}{{\large {\bf START PAGE COUNT \--- MAX 10 PAGES~~~~~}}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}
}\vspace{-.5cm}
\end{flushright}
}
\newcommand{\markEndPageLimit}{%
\vfill
\begin{flushright}
\textcolor{red}{{\large {\bf STOP PAGE COUNT \--- MAX 10 PAGES~~~~~}}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}
}
\end{flushright}
}


% To correctly align fancy headers.
% Courtesy of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88136/84485
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetHeadWidth}{\f@nch@setoffs}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\color{gray}{\ac{PropAcronym}\xspace\xspace - EF-ST}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\color{gray}{Part B - Page \thepage~of \pageref*{sec:letters}}}
\resetHeadWidth

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


% For CV
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


%List of acronyms used in the proposal 
%read the acronym package manual for details: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf
%\acs{PropAcronym} gives acronym [in square brackets]
%\acl{PropAcronym} gives long form of acronym, probably not used {in second set of braces}
%\acf{PropAcronym} gives both
\begin{acronym}
\acro{IF}{Individual Fellowships}
\acro{PropAcronym}[PROPOSAL ACRONYM]{This is my proposal's acronym}
\end{acronym}

\begin{document}
%mark proposal acronym as used, such that the short-hand form is always used by default.
\acused{PropAcronym}
%\begin{linenumbers}

% !TEX root = ./IF-2018-Part_B.tex

\newpage
\section{CV of the experienced researcher}
\label{sec:cv}

The CV is intrinsic to the evaluation of the whole proposal and is assessed throughout the three evaluation criteria by the expert evaluators. Ensure that the information provided in Parts A and B is fully consistent. Always mention full dates (dd/mm/yyyy) in your CV.\cite{schrock_molybdenum_1986}


%\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post a *compact* example document here directly? Off-site links for example documents are strongly discouraged due to possible link rot and the documents shown in the link are quite long and so not really suitable as an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: All I can say now is that `style=chem-acs,` selects a style that does not normally produce footnote citations. `chem-acs` produces numeric citations that can only be resolved with a bibliography at the end of your document. The `verbose` styles (like `verbose-inote`) produce full citations in footnotes (the first citation of each work is usually a copy of the whole bibliography entry) and does not necessarily need a final bibliography.

Comment: Hi moewe, thanks for your input. I have added a mwe.

Comment: Oh, that is quite a  lot of code. I ran the example and I got one citation in the footnote. Then I realised that the code still uses `\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` so I changed it to `\usepackage[style=chem-acs,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`. Now I get a normal numeric citation as expected. You will need a `\printbibliography` to resolve it. If you insist on footnote citations, try `\footfcullcite` instead of `\cite`.

Comment: Amazing, that seems to work. Unfortunately footnote citations are required for submission of this document, urgh. Note you have a typo in your response, it should be ```\footfullcite``` not ```\footfcullcite```. Would you like to post an answer to this question to resolve it, or should I? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verbose-inote` style produces footnote citations by default. But if you switch to `chem-acs` you select a style that produces numeric citations. Numeric styles like `chem-acs` rely on a bibliography at the end of the document, which you can produce with `\printbibliography`.

---

If you insist on `chem-acs` and want footnotes, the easiest way is probably to take `\footfullcite`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=chem-acs, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % ONLY for the example
Lorem \footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E.; Ryde, U. Journal of Computational Chemistry 1998, 19, 377–395.]