# How can I adjust the fancy footer and header margins to make align to text

Tags: footer

How can I adjust the fancy footer and header margins to make align to text?
[image]

this is my Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage {indentfirst}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lfoot {  Left    }

\cfoot {Page: \thepage/2}

\rfoot { Right  }

\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}

\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=0.7in}

\begin{document}

my Text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you must change the geometry `\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=0.7in}` change it before setting your page headings

Comment: Thank You so much, it worked . I really appreciate Your help.
this is my first question on this community. I found the answer within 12 seconds.
Thank You so much David Carlisle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fancyhdr not centering after changed geometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88133/fancyhdr-not-centering-after-changed-geometry)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.

Answer (score 0):

if you must change the geometry

```
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=0.7in}
```

change it before setting your page headings